# JavaScript: function for split

Tags: javascript, function

Anyone who knows how to pass the value of a/b/c. If selection is king then pass the value a b and c in different text box. If queen then pass the value d,e and f to the same text box. Can any one help me with the function that can do as my need.

```
        <select id="select" name="select" >
          <option value="">---Please select---</option>
          <option value="a/b/c">king</option>
          <option value="d/e/f">queen</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a" name="a" value=a required>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="b" name="b" value=b required>


        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c" name="c" value=c required>
```

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do? pass the values in a request?

Comment: I want to make a function that can split the value and place it to the text box

Comment: Who marked this as off-topic as *professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration* question? lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onchange event to your select element;

```
<select id="select" name="select" onchange="fn()">
      <option value="">---Please select---</option>
      <option value="a/b/c">king</option>
      <option value="d/e/f">queen</option>
    </select>
```

Then write the below javascript to achieve the goal:

```
function fn() {
   var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
   var arr_x = x.split('/');
   document.getElementById("a").value = arr_x[0];
   document.getElementById("b").value = arr_x[1];
   document.getElementById("c").value = arr_x[2];
}
```

Comment: use `addEventListener`, please!

Comment: thanks ivp your code helped me.

Comment: you are welcome...

Comment: can you give the question one vote someone has find my question not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a listener to your `select` component which then gets the value (in this example "a/b/c" or "d/e/f"). To get each individual letter here we use `split()` on the `/` delimiter and that retuns an array with each letter.

We then fetch all the elements that have the `form-control` class with `getElementsByClassName()` and for each of the elements we iterate through a loop which changes each of those input fields with the letter from the former array.

```js
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function () {
  var values = this.value.split("/");
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].value = values[i] || "";
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="select" name="select">
  <option value="">---Please select---</option>
  <option value="a/b/c">king</option>
  <option value="d/e/f">queen</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="a" name="a" value=a required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="b" name="b" value=b required>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="c" name="c" value=c required>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select').change(function(){
var ySelectedValue = $(this).val();
var ySelectedValueSplit = ySelectedValue.split("/");

$('#a').val(ySelectedValueSplit[0]);
$('#b').val(ySelectedValueSplit[1]);
$('#c').val(ySelectedValueSplit[2]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" name="select" >
          <option value="">---Please select---</option>
          <option value="a/b/c">king</option>
          <option value="d/e/f">queen</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a" name="a" value= required>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="b" name="b" value= required>


        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c" name="c" value= required>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, and its also jQuery which you should probably point out since OP didn't tag their question as such.